# Gradle and Team City: Overriding --init-script argument?

Tags: java, gradle, arguments, teamcity

Within my `Team City` Project (`Java` project with`gradle` build) I see that Team City adds the argument:

```
--init-script /path/to/file/init.gradle
```

Is there a way to *override* this argument to point to a different `init.gradle` script within a separate directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure, whether it is possible to do it via teamcity configuration without modifyng the sscript in plugin directory. But any way, you are able to override this property in you build configuration settings.

While you are providing build steps for Gradle, you may add command line aruments by setting the `Additional Gradle command line parameters` field. You are free to pass `--init-script /path/to/file/init.gradle` as a parameter and it will override the default one. Sure, you have to do it for all build steps, shich requires for such a modifications.

Alternatively, you may try to modify `init.gradle` script itself, within plugin directory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, appreciate it. So to clarify: if I add this as an additional gradle parameter it will override the one added automatically by Team City?

Comment: It will run gradle with both this parameters, but your one will override the default one, because custom parameters are passed after all defaults

Comment: I tried to do this and it seems that my argument is not overriding the default one? Within my Additional Gradle command line arguments I have the following: --no-daemon --init-script /path/to/my/new/file/init.gradle  , any help from this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For reference: Within my additional argument I am trying to point to an init.gradle file a different directory. This is because I have modified it and now want to use it rather than the default one. Thanks again

Comment: Could you check the log, it has to comtain the command line with grade run. Does it contain both args?

Comment: Yes the command line contains both arguments, firstly the default one, then straight after it it contains mine , however it still is not overriding it?

Comment: @java123999 I have a Gradle 2.8 and TC 8.0.4 and it works. Just to verify, try to provide some non-existing path as parameter. My build fails, because it can't locate init.script file

Comment: Ok so purposely make the build fail with a path that doesn't exist?

Comment: For reference, im using team city 7